# filter google calendar by regex using google app script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I only want to display certain entries in my google calendar.
I would like to use regular expressions for that (**^([0-9]+day)**.

in my prototype I get full of mistakes:

TypeError: "0"

```
function myFunction() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("sl5something@gmail.com")
  var now = new Date();
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(now)
  for(var i = 0; i<events.length;i++){
    title = events[i].getTitle()
    var ar = title.match(/^([0-9]+day)/)
      var preTitle = ar[0]; // <===== TypeError: "1"
      var postTitle = ar[1];
      if(preTitle){
        Browser.msgBox(preTitle + ":" + postTitle)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check if `ar` is not null and has length 2

Comment: i put it in the answer below.  If want send self a anwer below i will give you the check.

Comment: Thank you. But your answer is sufficient. I would recommend that you add a simple explanation before the code snippet as to why it works.

Answer (score 0):

this works as expected:

```
function myFunction() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("someEmail@gmail.com")
  var now = new Date();
  var events = cal.getEventsForDay(now)
  for(var i = 0; i<events.length;i++){
    title = events[i].getTitle()
    var ar = title.match(/^([0-9]+day)(.*)/)
    if(!ar) // <==== this helps
      continue
    var preTitle = ar[1]; // <===== no TypeError: "1"
    var postTitle = ar[2];
    Browser.msgBox(preTitle + " ### " + postTitle)
  }
}
```